# Javascript: push() to inner Dictionary-like object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Returning from a long break from JS, and cant figure out how to add to my data type.

Its like Like a `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>`:

```
Data = [
    { 
        id: "aa", 
        value: [
            { key: "this", value: "99" }, 
            { key: "that", value: "66" }
       ] 
    }
];
```

But How do I `push()` the inner and outer data types at the same time?

Comment: `Data[0].value.push({key: 'Check this', value: 'It Works!!!'});`

Comment: FYI, in Javascript they're called "objects".

Comment: `[]` is an array, `{}` is an object.

Comment: I copy-pasted poorly. In my actual usage it is an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to push to Data object, use `Data.push(yourObject);`

If you want to push to the inner object, use `Data[0].value.push(yourObject)`.

Comment: What if I still need to actually push the outer 'value' first, e.g. Data["value"] hasn't been added yet?

Comment: In that case, add `Data['value'] = []` before pushing anything. Once you added the empty array you can start pushing the objects.

Comment: I can reference 'value' during creation?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can either use `Data['value'] = []` or `Data.value = []`